# Separar un grafico en 2 paneles con diferentes datos

Tags: javascript, html

he intentado separar un grafico en dos bloques, es decir que al visualizarlo, visualice abajo un array de datos, y arriba otro array de datos.

```js
    initChart = () => {
        var dataSource = this.datosTest;
        var dataCaudal = this.datosCaudalimetro;

        this.chartOptions = {

            palette: 'Violet',
            dataSource,
            commonSeriesSettings: {
                argumentField: 'Date',
                valueField: 'Value',
                type: 'line',
            },
            seriesTemplate: {
                nameField: 'PPAParameterDesc',
            },
            format: {
                type: "fixedPoint",
                precision: 0
            },
            legend: {
                hoverMode: "excludePoints",
            },
            title: {
                text: `<b>${this.message} ${this.equipment}.</b>\n ${this.startTime}: ${this.startDate} \n ${this.endTime}: ${this.endDate}`,
            },

            valueAxis: {
                valueType: 'numeric',
                grid: {
                    opacity: 0.0,
                },
                label: {
                    customizeText() {
                        return `${this.valueText}`;
                    },
                },
            },
            argumentAxis: {
                type: 'continuous',
                grid: {
                    visible: false,
                    opacity: 0.5,
                },
                argumentAxis: {
                    label: {
                        customizeText() {
                            return `Day ${this.valueText}`;
                        },
                    },
                },
                valueAxis: {
                },
            },

            export: {
                enabled: true,
            },
            tooltip: {
                enabled: true,
                customizeTooltip(arg) {
                    return { text: `${arg.seriesName}\n${arg.value}\n${arg.argument.getHours()}:${arg.argument.getMinutes()}:${arg.argument.getSeconds()}` };
                }
            },
            scrollBar: {
                visible: true,
            },
            zoomAndPan: {
                valueAxis: 'both',
                argumentAxis: 'both',
                dragToZoom: true,
                allowMouseWheel: true,
                panKey: 'shift',
            },

            onLegendClick: (e) => {
                console.log(e)
                if (e.target.isVisible()) {
                    e.target.hide()
                } else {
                    e.target.show()
                }
            }
        }
```

La cosa es que he intentado añadiendo la propiedad "panes" para dividir como el grafico y en el datasource, poner o un array o otro, de la siguiente manera:

```js
initChart = () => {
        var dataSource = this.datosTest;
        var dataCaudal = this.datosCaudalimetro;

        this.chartOptions = {

            palette: 'Violet',
            dataSource: dataSource,
            commonSeriesSettings: {
                argumentField: 'Date',
                valueField: 'Value',
                type: 'line',
            },
            seriesTemplate: {
                nameField: 'PPAParameterDesc',
            },
            format: {
                type: "fixedPoint",
                precision: 0
            },
            legend: {
                hoverMode: "excludePoints",
            },
            title: {
                text: `<b>${this.message} ${this.equipment}.</b>\n ${this.startTime}: ${this.startDate} \n ${this.endTime}: ${this.endDate}`,
            },

            valueAxis: {
                valueType: 'numeric',
                grid: {
                    opacity: 0.0,
                },
                label: {
                    customizeText() {
                        return `${this.valueText}`;
                    },
                },
            },
            argumentAxis: {
                type: 'continuous',
                grid: {
                    visible: false,
                    opacity: 0.5,
                },
                label: {
                    customizeText() {
                        return `Day ${this.valueText}`;
                    },
                },
                valueAxis: {
                },
            },

            export: {
                enabled: true,
            },
            tooltip: {
                enabled: true,
                customizeTooltip(arg) {
                    return { text: `${arg.seriesName}\n${arg.value}\n${arg.argument.getHours()}:${arg.argument.getMinutes()}:${arg.argument.getSeconds()}` };
                }
            },
            scrollBar: {
                visible: true,
            },
            zoomAndPan: {
                valueAxis: 'both',
                argumentAxis: 'both',
                dragToZoom: true,
                allowMouseWheel: true,
                panKey: 'shift',
            },

            onLegendClick: (e) => {
                console.log(e)
                if (e.target.isVisible()) {
                    e.target.hide()
                } else {
                    e.target.show()
                }
            },
            
            // Paneles superior e inferior
            panes: [{
                name: 'top'
            }, {
                name: 'bottom'
            }],
            defaultPane: 'top',
            
            // Configuración del área superior
            series: [{
                pane: 'top',
                dataSource: dataCaudal,
                type: 'line',
                argumentField: 'Date',
                valueField: 'Value',
                name: 'Data Caudalimetro'
            }],
            argumentAxis: {
                pane: 'top',
                label: {
                    visible: false
                }
            },
            valueAxis: {
                pane: 'top',
                label: {
                    visible: false
                }
            },
            
            // Configuración del área inferior
            seriesTemplate: {
                nameField: 'PPAParameterDesc',
                pane: 'bottom'
            },
            dataSource: dataSource
        };
    }
```

Pero me sigue sin funcionar.
Alguien sabe como hacerlo o en que tengo problemas ?

Comment: Añado, que con el primer código es funcional, la única pega que tiene es que solo visualizo el dataSource, pero lo veo sin problemas.
En caso de no poder hacerse asi, se podría que teniendo todos los datos guardados en el datasource, dividir la grafica en dos partes, pero limitando el tamaño ?, es decir yo tengo datos que unicamente llegan a un valor de 100, la cosa es que tengo otros datos, que de 1000 no bajan, entonces me gustaria poner unos datos de 0 a 400 y los otros de 1000 a 4000, pero en una division de la grafica, ya que sino queda descompensado la grafica.

Comment: Que libreria estas usando?